# How can I make region checks for Playstation platform in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, ps4

I'm working on implementing GDPR (General Data Protection Regulation) checks for my PC and PSVR. For PC i'm doing a region and language check from Windows registry. I can't find any information of doing this for PlayStation. How can I get the current region and language from a PlayStation console?

The PC checks are like this:
1. Get current region - country code (using System.Localization)
2. Get language - language code 
3. Send a web request to a remote server to determine if the ip address is in EU

The unity web request is compatible with PS platforms. But we need to make additional checks like region and language from the device or player account to determine if user is in Europe.

Comment: Not so sure about this. But, can you print out the value of `SystemInfo.deviceModel` and put it in here? one way is to use SKU number of the device to determine the region of the device. But, I still think the best is to send a web request and determine the device location through its IP address.